Smetaniuk's Proof of Evans Conjecture
In our combinatorics courses, we have been taught about Smetaniuk's proof of Evans conjecture. I understand all of it but the construction from Latin square of order $n$ to the one of order $n+1$ with constant back diagonal. Therefore, I am seeking for an explanation with a concrete example. For instance, for the following Latin square $$\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&4&5&1\\3&4&5&1&2\\4&5&1&2&3\\5&1&2&3&4\end{matrix}$$ how do we apply Smetaniuk's algorithm on this?

It's really complicated... The only complete presentation I could find was in Latin Squares: New Developments in the Theory and Applications, Eds J Denes and A D
Keedwell, North Holland, Amsterdam, 1991, 217-265. The specific chapter was C.C. Lindner, "Embedding theorems for partial Latin squares".

Actually, I found a much more readable source! See Proofs from the Book, 4th ed, in the chapter titled "Completing Latin Squares".

The details of this construction are described in Proofs from the Book, 4th ed, Chapter 32. The construction is a little complicated to describe in full generality, but I can illustrate how Smetianuk's construcution works on your particular square.
We start by appending a column of $6$'s to the right side of the given square.
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&3&4&5&1&6\\
3&4&5&1&2&6\\
4&5&1&2&3&6\\
5&1&2&3&4&6\end{matrix}
$$
One by one, we will then switch these $6$'s with the corresponding entry on the back diagonal of the original square. We will only make switches between two elements in the same row. We do this in the order from top to bottom. The first switch is the easiest:
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&4&\color{blue}6&\color{blue}5\\
2&3&4&5&1&6\\
3&4&5&1&2&6\\
4&5&1&2&3&6\\
5&1&2&3&4&6\end{matrix}
$$
Next, we switch the $6$ in the second row with the back diagonal entry $5$ in the second row. However, this creates a problem, as there are two $5$'s in the last column now. We must fix this problem before moving on to the next $6$.
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&4&6&\color{red}5\\
2&3&4&\color{blue}6&1&\color{red}5\\
3&4&5&1&2&6\\
4&5&1&2&3&6\\
5&1&2&3&4&6\end{matrix}
$$
The problem is that there is an earlier entry in the last column which is equal to the one which was just switched in. To fix this, we will switch the earlier entry into the same column that the new entry came from. This fixes the issue.
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&\color{blue}5&6&\color{blue}4\\
2&3&4&\color{blue}6&1&\color{blue}5\\
3&4&5&1&2&6\\
4&5&1&2&3&6\\
5&1&2&3&4&6\end{matrix}
$$
We now move onto the $6$ in the next row. Again, switching in the $6$ with $5$ on the back diagonal creates a problem, because there is already a $5$ in the last column. To fix this, we switch the offending earlier $5$ with the $4$ in that same column. However, this creates another problem, as there is already a $4$ above. Again, we fix this is the same way, switching the $4$ with the three in the same column. The superscripts below indicate the order that the switches happen.
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2&\color{blue}4^3&5&6&\color{blue}3^3\\
2&3&\color{blue}5^2&6&1&\color{blue}4^2\\
3&4&\color{blue}6^1&1&2&\color{blue}5^1\\
4&5&1&2&3&6\\
5&1&2&3&4&6\end{matrix}
$$
The process continues exactly as described. It turns out that you picked the worst case Latin square which requires the most correction switches. In the fourth row, you will need four switches total, and for the final $6$ in the fifth row, you need five switches total. The final result of all of the switchings is below. Finally, to complete this to a Latin square, you just need to add in the final row at the top.
$$
\begin{matrix}
2&3&4&5&6&1\\
3&4&5&6&1&2\\
4&5&6&1&2&3\\
5&6&1&2&3&4\\
6&1&2&3&4&5\end{matrix}
$$
In order for this construction to be complete, you need to prove that the process of switching entries to correct previous problems actually stops. This is proven in Proofs from the Book, but I can give a sketch here. When you are working on the $k^\text{th}$ row, you are switching between entries with coordinates $(1,n+1),(2,n+1),\dots,(k,n+1)$ in the last column, and entries $(1,n+1-k),(2,n+1-k),\dots,(k,n+1-k)$ in the $(n+1-k)^\text{th}$ column. You form a graph with these $2k$ entries as vertices, connected by edges as follows. Two entries in the same row are joined by an edge, and two entries that are filled with the same number are joined by an edge. This graph has maximum degree $2$. The vertex at $(k,n+1)$ has degree $1$, since it is initially filled with $n+1$, which is not present in the original square. Starting from vertex $(k,n+1)$, you can trace a unique path through the graph, and this path exactly corresponds to the sequence of correctional switches performed by the algorithm. This path must have a second endpoint, hence the sequence terminates.

So it is an another brilliant application of hand-shaking lemma. Great appreciation for you clear explanation!
